# Images instead of radio buttons or dropdown list?

Tags: 6, nodes

I would like the user to choose the category when he creates a new node content. However, instead of radio buttons or dropdown list I would like to have selectable images, with exactly the same logic. Is it possible to somehow ovveride radio buttons / dropdown lists with options being displayed as images? So, for example instead of a radio button with 'Cars' label I would like to have a picture of a car, then for the next category another picture, etc. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a combination of a little JQuery and CSS.

Here's some starting points

- http://codeloaded.com/fullscreen-preview/jquery-image-checkbox
- http://aaronweyenberg.com/90/pretty-checkboxes-with-jquery
- http://codecanyon.net/item/jic-jquery-image-checkbox/full_screen_preview/676874
- http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/

Then use a custom module to load the JS when needed using [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) typically instantiated with a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).

Something like this:

```
/**
* Add example.js to content type 'car' create/edit form for example.module
*/
function example_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ('car_node_form' == $form_id) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'example').'example.js');
}
```

You can find more examples for detecting different forms and patterns on the [hook snippets page](http://drupal.org/node/651106).

Comment: Links are not anymore available.

Comment: Looks like there are better solutions available today using css3. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345886/styling-radio-inputs?lq=1 which uses image replacement via the label element.  Of course if you need the label element jquery could be used to replace the checkboxes with images.